# Error in ConfusionMatrix the data and reference factors must have the same number of levels

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret

I've trained a tree model with R caret. I'm now trying to generate a confusion matrix and keep getting the following error:

> Error in confusionMatrix.default(predictionsTree,  testdata$catgeory)
>   : the data and reference factors must have the same number of levels

```
prob <- 0.5 #Specify class split
singleSplit <- createDataPartition(modellingData2$category, p=prob,
                                   times=1, list=FALSE)
cvControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=5)
traindata <- modellingData2[singleSplit,]
testdata <- modellingData2[-singleSplit,]
treeFit <- train(traindata$category~., data=traindata,
                 trControl=cvControl, method="rpart", tuneLength=10)
predictionsTree <- predict(treeFit, testdata)
confusionMatrix(predictionsTree, testdata$catgeory)
```

The error occurs when generating the confusion matrix. The levels are the same on both objects. I cant figure out what the problem is. Their structure and levels are given below.
They should be the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated as its making me cracked!!

```
> str(predictionsTree)
 Factor w/ 30 levels "16-Merchant Service Charge",..: 28 22 22 22 22 6 6 6 6 6 ...
> str(testdata$category)
 Factor w/ 30 levels "16-Merchant Service Charge",..: 30 30 7 7 7 7 7 30 7 7 ...

> levels(predictionsTree)
 [1] "16-Merchant Service Charge"   "17-Unpaid Cheque Fee"         "18-Gov. Stamp Duty"           "Misc"                         "26-Standard Transfer Charge" 
 [6] "29-Bank Giro Credit"          "3-Cheques Debit"              "32-Standing Order - Debit"    "33-Inter Branch Payment"      "34-International"            
[11] "35-Point of Sale"             "39-Direct Debits Received"    "4-Notified Bank Fees"         "40-Cash Lodged"               "42-International Receipts"   
[16] "46-Direct Debits Paid"        "56-Credit Card Receipts"      "57-Inter Branch"              "58-Unpaid Items"              "59-Inter Company Transfers"  
[21] "6-Notified Interest Credited" "61-Domestic"                  "64-Charge Refund"             "66-Inter Company Transfers"   "67-Suppliers"                
[26] "68-Payroll"                   "69-Domestic"                  "73-Credit Card Payments"      "82-CHAPS Fee"                 "Uncategorised"   

> levels(testdata$category)
 [1] "16-Merchant Service Charge"   "17-Unpaid Cheque Fee"         "18-Gov. Stamp Duty"           "Misc"                         "26-Standard Transfer Charge" 
 [6] "29-Bank Giro Credit"          "3-Cheques Debit"              "32-Standing Order - Debit"    "33-Inter Branch Payment"      "34-International"            
[11] "35-Point of Sale"             "39-Direct Debits Received"    "4-Notified Bank Fees"         "40-Cash Lodged"               "42-International Receipts"   
[16] "46-Direct Debits Paid"        "56-Credit Card Receipts"      "57-Inter Branch"              "58-Unpaid Items"              "59-Inter Company Transfers"  
[21] "6-Notified Interest Credited" "61-Domestic"                  "64-Charge Refund"             "66-Inter Company Transfers"   "67-Suppliers"                
[26] "68-Payroll"                   "69-Domestic"                  "73-Credit Card Payments"      "82-CHAPS Fee"                 "Uncategorised"
```

Comment: In your error, `category` is spelled `catgeory`. If the problem is not related, what's the output of `identical(levels(predictionsTree),levels(testdata$category))` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for that i ammended the silly spelling mistake....doh!!! I ran the identical function and it outputted [1] TRUE.........now I'm getting the following error when I run the confusionMatrix function.....Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : 
  all arguments must have the same length

Comment: Check for another misspelled `catgeory`, check `length(testdata$category)` and `length(predictionsTree`, check also your summary of both vectors. If you want just have a simple confusion matrix : `table(predictionsTree,testdata$category)`

Answer (score 24):

Try use:

```
confusionMatrix(table(Argument 1, Argument 2))
```

Thats worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe your model is not predicting a certain factor.
Use the `table()` function instead of `confusionMatrix()` to see if that is the problem.

Comment: You can add this as comment.

Comment: I found this very helpful, yet now I am wondering, it doesn't seem like there is much of a difference between the two. Is it only graphical?

Comment: If this is the case, then, how can we fix or work it around gracefully?

Answer (score 4):

Try specifying `na.pass` for the `na.action` option:

```
predictionsTree <- predict(treeFit, testdata,na.action = na.pass)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change them into a data frame and then use them in confusionMatrix function:

```
pridicted <- factor(predict(treeFit, testdata))
real <- factor(testdata$catgeory)

my_data1 <- data.frame(data = pridicted, type = "prediction")
my_data2 <- data.frame(data = real, type = "real")
my_data3 <- rbind(my_data1,my_data2)

# Check if the levels are identical
identical(levels(my_data3[my_data3$type == "prediction",1]) , levels(my_data3[my_data3$type == "real",1]))

confusionMatrix(my_data3[my_data3$type == "prediction",1], my_data3[my_data3$type == "real",1],  dnn = c("Prediction", "Reference"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but went ahead and changed it after reading data file like so..

`data = na.omit(data)`

Thanks all for pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Might be there are missing values in the testdata, Add the following line before "predictionsTree <- predict(treeFit, testdata)" to remove NAs. I had the same error and now it works for me.

```
testdata <- testdata[complete.cases(testdata),]
```

Answer (score 0):

The length problem you're running into is probably due to the presence of NAs in the training set -- either drop the cases that are not complete, or impute so that you do not have missing values.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you installed the package with all its dependencies:

```
install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)

confusionMatrix( table(prediction, true_value) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data contains NAs then sometimes it will be considered as a factor level,So omit these NAs initially

```
DF = na.omit(DF)
```

Then,if your model fit is predicting some incorrect level,then it is better to use tables

```
confusionMatrix(table(Arg1, Arg2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, I solved it by using R ordered factor data type.

```
levels <- levels(predictionsTree)
levels <- levels[order(levels)]    
table(ordered(predictionsTree,levels), ordered(testdata$catgeory, levels))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the data type! My issue was that data had type int and reference had num. They need the same type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by sharing the an example with code of how to solve it. Generally, try to be as specific as possible.