# Confusion Matrix Levels Error with non unique test data

Tags: r

I am attempting to generate a confusion matrix with predicted data and actual data. I receive an error that the levels are not equal and I receive the error when both variables are read as factors. When I checked the levels I believe the issue is because the test data has many repeated values and thus a lower number of levels than the predicted values which are all unique. Is there a way to force the level of test data such that it will be equal to the predictions?

```
confusionMatrix(as.factor(sale.pred),as.factor(housing.test.df$SalePrice))
```

`sale.pred` are the forecasted values and `housing.test.df$SalePrice` are the actual values. As stated, sale.pred has no duplicate values and so its level is equal to the number of rows but `housing.test.df$SalePrice` has duplicate values and so its number of levels is `< n` as the number of rows.

Comment: Check the following previously asked questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002013/error-in-confusion-matrix-the-data-and-reference-factors-must-have-the-same-nu   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801452/error-in-confusionmatrix-the-data-and-reference-factors-must-have-the-same-numbe

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and into the https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex package

Comment: I tried manually setting the levels between 60,000 and 755000 which seems to be the range 

sale.pred <-  predict(reg, housing.pca)
sale.pred <- as.factor(sale.pred)

actual <-  as.factor(housing.test.df$SalePrice)
levels(actual) <- c(60000:755000)
levels(sale.pred)<-c(60000:755000)

confusionMatrix(sale.pred,actual)

 but received the error

Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements